# Bluetooth does not detect device

Tags: bluetooth

I have Dell inspiron 3521 and Ubuntu 12.04.
Wireless is working perfectly but bluetooth does not detect any device.
result of `sudo rfkill list` is

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

Please help me regarding this.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

At me this problem appear if the bluetooth is disabled when system is starting, for me work this solution: open System Settings > Bluetooth and enable if it is disabled, or disable and enable if it is enabled; Restart and try again.

Answer (score 0):

it says [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup) that you have to install the bluetooth driver from dell's website on windows in order for it to work on ubuntu.

Comment: `bccmd psset -r -s implementation 0x028c 0x0001` shows unsupported manufacturer message in terminal.

Comment: I didn't worked.

Comment: Those instructions don't work for 16.04.